# CABasicAnimation not working on CAGradientLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cabasicanimation, cagradientlayer

I'm trying to create a Shimmer effect to a UIButton, so i've subclassed it and tried to start the animation, but nothing happens. I can see the gradient on the button, but it is not animating. What am I doing wrong?

This is how it looks:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
class ShimmerButton: UIButton {
    
    private var gradientColorOne : CGColor = UIColor(white: 0.85, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
    private var gradientColorTwo : CGColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    
    func addGradientLayer() -> CAGradientLayer {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.colors = [self.gradientColorOne, self.gradientColorTwo, self.gradientColorOne]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
        let top = self.layer.sublayers?.last
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, above: top)
        return gradientLayer
    }
    
    func addAnimation(duration: Double, repeatCount: Float) -> CABasicAnimation {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        animation.fromValue = [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0]
        animation.toValue = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
        animation.repeatCount = repeatCount
        animation.duration = duration
        return animation
    }
    
    func startAnimating(duration: Double, repeatCount: Float) {
        let gradientLayer = self.addGradientLayer()
        let animation = self.addAnimation(duration: duration, repeatCount: repeatCount)
        gradientLayer.add(animation, forKey: "anim")
    }
}
```

Starting the animation:

```
self.button.startAnimating(duration: 0.9, repeatCount: .infinity)
```

Code sample has been taken from [here](https://github.com/VasudhaJha/ShimmerAnimationComplete).

Comment: While Apple's docs do state `The gradient stops are specified as values between 0 and 1`, I've seen many examples using values outside that range, so I don't think that's the issue. I tried your code - exactly as you posted - and it works without problem. The issue is likely whatever else you are doing to that button's appearance, which is not shown in your code here.

Comment: I'm not doing anything to it, just set a backgroundImage.

Comment: Here is what I get using your unmodified code, with an image set as the button's background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYJwH.gif

Comment: That's weird because in my case the gradient layer mask wont animate.

Comment: Note that as your code is written you can't remove your gradientLayer once you've added it. I updated the ShimmerButton class in my answer to save the gradientLayer to an instance var so you can start/stop the animation and remove the gradient layer as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Animating the positions property works just fine.

I wrote a playground that creates a simple gradient animation. It looks like this:

[image]

I also incorporated the OPs ShimmerButton (With some changes to make it so you can start/stop the shimmer animation. The shimmer animation looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code for that playground:

```
 //: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ShimmerButton: UIButton {
    public var animating = false

    private var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer?
    private var gradientColorOne : CGColor = UIColor(white: 0.85, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
    private var gradientColorTwo : CGColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 0.5).cgColor

    private func addGradientLayer() -> CAGradientLayer? {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.colors = [self.gradientColorOne, self.gradientColorTwo, self.gradientColorOne]
        gradientLayer.locations = [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0]
        let top = self.layer.sublayers?.last
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, above: top)
        return gradientLayer
    }

    public func addAnimation(duration: Double, repeatCount: Float) -> CABasicAnimation {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        animation.fromValue = [-1.0, -0.5, 0.0]
        animation.toValue = [1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
        animation.repeatCount = repeatCount
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.delegate = self
        return animation
    }

    public func stopAnimating() {
        guard let  gradientLayer = gradientLayer  else { return }
        gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        gradientLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.gradientLayer = nil
        animating = false
    }

    public func startAnimating(duration: Double, repeatCount: Float) {
        if !animating {
            animating = true
            gradientLayer = self.addGradientLayer()
            let animation = self.addAnimation(duration: duration, repeatCount: repeatCount)
            gradientLayer?.add(animation, forKey: "anim")
        }
    }
}

extension ShimmerButton: CAAnimationDelegate {
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished: Bool) {
        animating = false
        if finished {
            gradientLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
            gradientLayer = nil;
        }
    }
}

class GradientView: UIView {

    var animationIsLeft: Bool = false
    var animating = false

    static override var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    public func animateGradient() {
        animating = true
        animateGradientStep()
    }

    public func animateGradientStep() {
        guard animating,
              let layer = layer as? CAGradientLayer else { return }
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"locations")
        animation.duration = 0.5
        animationIsLeft = !animationIsLeft
        animation.fromValue = animationIsLeft ? [0, 0.1, 1] : [0, 0.9, 1.0]
        let toValue = !animationIsLeft ? [0, 0.1, 1] : [0, 0.9, 1.0]
        animation.toValue = toValue
        animation.delegate = self
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.02) {
            layer.locations = toValue.map { NSNumber(value: $0) }
        }
        layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }

    func doInitSetup() {
        guard let layer = layer as? CAGradientLayer else { return }
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        layer.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]
        layer.locations = [0, 0.1, 1]
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        doInitSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        doInitSetup()
    }
}

extension GradientView: CAAnimationDelegate {
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        animateGradientStep()
    }
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    var gradientView: GradientView?
    var button: ShimmerButton?

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.view = view

        gradientView = GradientView()
        if  let gradientView = gradientView {
            gradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(gradientView)
            gradientView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            gradientView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
            gradientView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            gradientView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            gradientView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        }

        button = ShimmerButton()
        guard let button = button else { return }
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if gradientView?.animating == true {
            gradientView?.animating = false
        } else {
            gradientView?.animateGradient()
        }
        guard let button = button else { return }
        if button.animating == true {
            button.stopAnimating()
        } else {
            button.startAnimating(duration: 1.0, repeatCount: Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: So why the down-vote? My answer is an attempt to confirm that animating the locations property of a gradient view works as expected. (I since added the OP's ShimmerButton to the playground.)