# UIView: animate a gradient inifinitely in the same given direction?

Tags: ios, uiview, caanimation, cagradientlayer

I would like to add a `CAAnimation` to a gradient and apply it to a `UIView`, looking like this:

[image]

The idea is that 20% of the gradient is fully white, and the fully blue part moves from left to right, and when it comes to the right edge of the screen (end of animation), I want to give the user the feeling that it's starting from the left edge again (start of animation again).

I am however a complete beginner when it comes to `CAGradientLayer`, so I don't really know what to do. This is what I wrote but it's still far from what I want to achieve.

```
let loadingView = UIView(frame: frame)
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()     
gradient.frame = frame
gradient.colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
animation.fromValue = [0.0, 0.5]
animation.toValue = [0.0, 1.0]
animation.duration = 1.5
animation.autoreverses = false
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
gradient.add(animation, forKey: nil)
view.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Also one last question, if I hide the `UIView` containing the `CAGradientLayer` using the `isHidden` property, it doesn't actually remove that layer from the screen. How can I do this?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What you have is a good basis for the animation. But the rest of your code makes no sense. In particular you create loadingView and then you never use it; you just throw it away. Hard to see what you expect

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67959614/6257435 ... the `ShimmerButton` class appears to do exactly what you're asking. (I have no idea why it got downvoted, or why it was never accepted, as it directly solved that user's question).

Comment: @DonMag I followed the example, it fits perfectly my needs. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `LoadingView` with a blue background color. Create a transparent gradient with a white component:

```swift
let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
gradient.frame = loadingView.frame
gradient.colors = [
    UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0), // It is important to use white, not clear color
    UIColor.white, 
    UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0)
].map { $0.cgColor }
gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 1.0] // The number of locations matches the number of colors
// Horizontal direction
gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0)
```

Add a gradient layer:

```swift
loadingView.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
```

Animate the movement of the layer like this:

```swift
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
animation.fromValue = -loadingView.frame.width
animation.toValue = loadingView.frame.width
animation.duration = 1.5
animation.repeatCount = .infinity

gradient.add(animation, forKey: "loadingAnimation")
```